# How to create a Igraph network from a data frame where edges are equal to multiple row values?

Tags: r, igraph

I am attempting to apply social network analysis to voting habits in Congress and am having difficulties building my network. I have a data.frame of 100  senators and how they sponsored 20 bills (where the value represents different sponsorship degrees). A simplified version looks as follows:

< d

```
  X AkakaDanielK AlexanderLamar AllardWayne BarrassoJohn
1 B1            0              2           1            2
2 B2            0              0           0            0
3 B3            0              0           0            0
4 B4            0              0           0            0
5 B5            0              0           0            0
6 B6            0              0           0            0
```

I cannot figure out how to make the columns the vertices and the edges the shared sponsorship of a bill. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this task, you need to transform the matrix. Here I simply replicate your data without the right names and add a few edges (otherwise you will end up with only one senator being connected to him or herself multiple times):

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 6, ncol = 4)
colnames(m) <- letters[1:4]
rownames(m) <- 1:6
m[] <- sample(0:2, 24, replace = T, prob = c(.5,.3,.2))
```

Using the `igraph` approach, you can use the function `graph_from_incidence_matrix`, which results in a two-mode graph of both senators and bills as vertices:

```
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(m, directed = F, multiple = T)
```

and then transform the graph into the one-mode-projection, consisting solely of the senators connected through the bills they share:

```
g_sponsors <- bipartite.projection(g, multiplicity = T)[[2]]
```

Another less type intensive way is using base R for matrix transformations and then read it in as an adjacency matrix:

```
m_sponsors <- t(m) %*% m
g_sponsors <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m_sponsors, weighted = T)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It worked well. On that note, if I wanted a network of only senators with a lot of connections, where it only retains edges between senators when the number of
bills they co-sponsored is in the top quartile, would I divide the data frame before turning it into a network, or is there a way to do this after you create the network?

Comment: You can do both. There is the `delete.edges` function (2) that deletes certain edges or you can set the values in the matrix (1):

     `m_sponsors[m_sponsors <= quantile(E(g_sponsors)$weight, .75)] <-  0`
 
or (2):

     `g_top <- delete.edges(g_sponsors, which(E(g_sponsors)$weight >=      quantile(E(g_sponsors)$weight, .75)))`